# Importing data into new database configuration

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I had a website, with an sql server database. I decided to create a new version of the site, so I downloaded the database + website onto my local dev PC, and added a whole bunch of stuff to both - in particular, I added lots of new stored procedures, columns and tables to the database, while leaving the existing data for the site in place while doing this.

It is now time to launch the new version. Of course, while working on the new version, the data in the database on the live site has changed - new users have signed up and so on, so I can't just push the dev enviroment database live, as this would lose data.

What is the best way to import all the data from the existing database into the new database configuration? Should I take the existing database, and then add all the columns, procs, tables, indexes and so on in to it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) or other comparison tools to make the production database look like your dev database. If budget is a concern you can see plenty of alternatives in [this blog post](http://www.onetooneglobal.com/otocorporate-posts/2009/06/01/the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/).

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server Management Studio , right click on your local database -> Task -> Generate Scripts, and then you'll be able to select your SP/Functions and then execute these script against the production database

Comment: While this will help for new objects, it won't really help for objects that have changed (most importantly tables with new / renamed / dropped columns).

Comment: I agree with you but he said that he "added a whole bunch of stuff", the script tool will work for new column no ?

Comment: Generating a "create table" script will try to create a new table. Management Studio isn't going to know which columns are "new" compared to some other copy of the database. Have you tried it?

Comment: you're right it doesn't provide any script for updating a table